# Conditional evaluation with unnamed option ISC DHCPD

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhcpcd

I would like to know how one properly checks for unnamed dhcp options. [This link for configuring UEFI](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pxe-boot-uefi) is where I got the inspiration. However, I'm completely lost because not even the latest ISC DHCP knows what to do with `option architecture-type` as depicted.

I've been trying to use the "unnamed option" via `option option-93` in the following manner

```
if option option-93 = 02:00:07 {
    filename "ABootFile.efi";
} else {
    filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

The problem is, even though [this manual page](https://man.openbsd.org/dhcp-options.5) shows this as the syntax for `option option-<dec_num>` when I check this with `dhcpd -t -cf /path/to/dhcpd.conf` it complains that *no option-93 defined in name dhcp*.  I've even built the latest version of ISC DHCPD and this error shows.  Because the latest ISC DHCPD server chokes on *architecture-type* and *option-93*, I wonder if the Red Hat link is bogus or they are using a different server.

What is the proper way to check for the value in option 93 of DHCP for client system architecture?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the secret sauce thanks [to this discussion thread](https://community.theforeman.org/t/uefi-dhcpd-conf/9793/3). Apparently, one must "define" the option (I'm assuming, I haven't yet confirmed this understanding from DHCPD docs). I needed this prior to the conditional that I had above

```
option architecture code 93 = unsigned integer 16;
. . .
class "PXEClients" {
   match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
   if option architecture = 00:07 {
      filename "ABootFile.efi";
   } else {
      filename "pxelinux.0";
   }
}
```